# How to manually set TitlePane height or make it adapt to its content

Tags: user-interface, javafx, layout, scenebuilder

I would like to get a layout like this:
[image: goal]

Multiple titled panes, each one with a different content.

The problem is that by default not all elements inside the titledPane are visible ([ScreenShot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9yRj.png), the HBox with ChoiceBox, Label and Spinner aren't visible), and if I try to specify a prefHeight for the TitledPane (which is not recommended by the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TitledPane.html)) a blank space remain when the titled pane is closed ([ScreenShot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpFRf.png)).

How can I make a titled pane adapt to its content or specify a preferredHeight without creating blank spaces on close?

Here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Spinner?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.SplitPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TitledPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<StackPane prefHeight="989.0" prefWidth="1240.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/16" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <AnchorPane StackPane.alignment="TOP_LEFT">
         <children>
            <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.55" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
              <items>
                <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="100.0">
                     <children>
                        <ScrollPane fitToWidth="true" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                           <content>
                              <VBox>
                                 <children>
                                  <TitledPane alignment="TOP_LEFT" contentDisplay="TOP" nodeOrientation="LEFT_TO_RIGHT" text="TITLED PANE 1">
                                       <content>
                                          <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                                             <children>
                                                <VBox prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0">
                                                   <children>
                                                      <TableView minHeight="200.0" prefHeight="171.0" prefWidth="297.0">
                                                         <columns>
                                                            <TableColumn prefWidth="87.0" text="C1" />
                                                            <TableColumn minWidth="0.0" prefWidth="63.0" text="C2" />
                                                         </columns>
                                                      </TableView>
                                                      <HBox prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                                                         <children>
                                                            <ChoiceBox prefWidth="150.0" />
                                                            <Label text="some label" />
                                                            <Spinner />
                                                         </children>
                                                      </HBox>
                                                   </children>
                                                </VBox>
                                             </children>
                                          </AnchorPane>
                                       </content>
                                  </TitledPane>
                                  <TitledPane alignment="TOP_LEFT" contentDisplay="TOP" nodeOrientation="LEFT_TO_RIGHT" text="TITLED PANE 2">
                                       <content>
                                          <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                                             <children>
                                                <TableView layoutX="14.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="171.0" prefWidth="297.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0">
                                                   <columns>
                                                      <TableColumn prefWidth="87.0" text="C1" />
                                                      <TableColumn minWidth="0.0" prefWidth="63.0" text="C2" />
                                                   </columns>
                                                </TableView>
                                             </children>
                                          </AnchorPane>
                                       </content>
                                  </TitledPane>
                                  <TitledPane alignment="TOP_LEFT" contentDisplay="TOP" nodeOrientation="LEFT_TO_RIGHT" text="TITLED PANE 3">
                                       <content>
                                          <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                                             <children>
                                                <TableView layoutX="14.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="171.0" prefWidth="297.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0">
                                                   <columns>
                                                      <TableColumn prefWidth="87.0" text="C1" />
                                                      <TableColumn minWidth="0.0" prefWidth="63.0" text="C2" />
                                                   </columns>
                                                </TableView>
                                             </children>
                                          </AnchorPane>
                                       </content>
                                  </TitledPane>
                                    <TitledPane alignment="TOP_LEFT" contentDisplay="TOP" nodeOrientation="LEFT_TO_RIGHT" text="TITLED PANE 4">
                                       <content>
                                          <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="480.0">
                                             <children>
                                                <TableView layoutX="14.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="171.0" prefWidth="297.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0">
                                                   <columns>
                                                      <TableColumn prefWidth="87.0" text="C1" />
                                                      <TableColumn minWidth="0.0" prefWidth="63.0" text="C2" />
                                                   </columns>
                                                </TableView>
                                             </children>
                                          </AnchorPane>
                                       </content>
                                    </TitledPane>
                                 </children>
                              </VBox>
                           </content>
                        </ScrollPane>
                     </children>
                  </AnchorPane>
                <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" />
              </items>
            </SplitPane>
         </children>
         <padding>
            <Insets bottom="80.0" />
         </padding>
      </AnchorPane>
      <VBox alignment="CENTER" maxHeight="80.0" style="-fx-background-color: grey;" StackPane.alignment="BOTTOM_CENTER">
         <children>
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="FIXED BUTTON">
               <font>
                  <Font size="24.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
         </children>
      </VBox>
   </children>
</StackPane>
```

Comment: My guess is set a max hight on the `TableView`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need to put the `VBox` as the content node of the first `TitledPane`. In Scene Buider right mouse click on the `AnchorPane` and choose *"Unwrap"*. The part of the FXML should look like this then:

```xml
<TitledPane alignment="TOP_LEFT" contentDisplay="TOP" nodeOrientation="LEFT_TO_RIGHT" text="TITLED PANE 1">
    <content>
          <VBox prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0"> <!-- VBox direct content node instead of AnchorPane -->
              <children>
                  <TableView minHeight="200.0" prefHeight="171.0" prefWidth="297.0">
                      <columns>
                          <TableColumn prefWidth="87.0" text="C1" />
                          <TableColumn minWidth="0.0" prefWidth="63.0" text="C2" />
                      </columns>
                  </TableView>
                  <HBox prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                      <children>
                          <ChoiceBox prefWidth="150.0" />
                          <Label text="some label" />
                          <Spinner />
                      </children>
                  </HBox>
              </children>
          </VBox>
    </content>
</TitledPane>
```

Comment: I didn't think it was so simple. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I set everything thing to `USE_COMPUTER_SIZE` and then set the `TableViews` max-width to `MAX_VALUE` and max-height to 200. I hope this works for you!

```
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Spinner?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.SplitPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TitledPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<StackPane prefHeight="989.0" prefWidth="1240.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/15.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <AnchorPane StackPane.alignment="TOP_LEFT">
         <children>
            <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.55" minWidth="-Infinity" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
              <items>
                <AnchorPane>
                     <children>
                        <ScrollPane fitToWidth="true" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                           <content>
                              <VBox>
                                 <children>
                                  <TitledPane alignment="TOP_LEFT" contentDisplay="TOP" nodeOrientation="LEFT_TO_RIGHT" text="TITLED PANE 1">
                                       <content>
                                          <AnchorPane>
                                             <children>
                                                <VBox alignment="CENTER" spacing="2.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0">
                                                   <children>
                                                      <TableView maxHeight="200.0" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308">
                                                         <columns>
                                                            <TableColumn maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefWidth="87.0" text="C1" />
                                                            <TableColumn maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minWidth="0.0" prefWidth="63.0" text="C2" />
                                                         </columns>
                                                      </TableView>
                                                      <HBox alignment="CENTER_LEFT" spacing="2.0">
                                                         <children>
                                                            <ChoiceBox prefWidth="150.0" />
                                                            <Label text="some label" />
                                                            <Spinner />
                                                         </children>
                                                         <VBox.margin>
                                                            <Insets />
                                                         </VBox.margin>
                                                      </HBox>
                                                   </children>
                                                </VBox>
                                             </children>
                                          </AnchorPane>
                                       </content>
                                  </TitledPane>
                                  <TitledPane alignment="TOP_LEFT" contentDisplay="TOP" nodeOrientation="LEFT_TO_RIGHT" text="TITLED PANE 2">
                                       <content>
                                          <AnchorPane>
                                             <children>
                                                <TableView layoutX="14.0" layoutY="14.0" maxHeight="200.0" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0">
                                                   <columns>
                                                      <TableColumn prefWidth="87.0" text="C1" />
                                                      <TableColumn minWidth="0.0" prefWidth="63.0" text="C2" />
                                                   </columns>
                                                </TableView>
                                             </children>
                                          </AnchorPane>
                                       </content>
                                  </TitledPane>
                                  <TitledPane alignment="TOP_LEFT" contentDisplay="TOP" nodeOrientation="LEFT_TO_RIGHT" text="TITLED PANE 3">
                                       <content>
                                          <AnchorPane>
                                             <children>
                                                <TableView layoutX="14.0" layoutY="14.0" maxHeight="200.0" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0">
                                                   <columns>
                                                      <TableColumn prefWidth="87.0" text="C1" />
                                                      <TableColumn minWidth="0.0" prefWidth="63.0" text="C2" />
                                                   </columns>
                                                </TableView>
                                             </children>
                                          </AnchorPane>
                                       </content>
                                  </TitledPane>
                                    <TitledPane alignment="TOP_LEFT" contentDisplay="TOP" nodeOrientation="LEFT_TO_RIGHT" text="TITLED PANE 4">
                                       <content>
                                          <AnchorPane>
                                             <children>
                                                <TableView layoutX="14.0" layoutY="14.0" maxHeight="200.0" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0">
                                                   <columns>
                                                      <TableColumn prefWidth="87.0" text="C1" />
                                                      <TableColumn minWidth="0.0" prefWidth="63.0" text="C2" />
                                                   </columns>
                                                </TableView>
                                             </children>
                                          </AnchorPane>
                                       </content>
                                    </TitledPane>
                                 </children>
                              </VBox>
                           </content>
                        </ScrollPane>
                     </children>
                  </AnchorPane>
                <AnchorPane />
              </items>
            </SplitPane>
         </children>
         <padding>
            <Insets bottom="80.0" />
         </padding>
      </AnchorPane>
      <VBox alignment="CENTER" maxHeight="80.0" style="-fx-background-color: grey;" StackPane.alignment="BOTTOM_CENTER">
         <children>
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="FIXED BUTTON">
               <font>
                  <Font size="24.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
         </children>
      </VBox>
   </children>
</StackPane>
```

Comment: Thank you! It works but Anko's answer it's a bit cleaner because i just have to delete a node.